# Launching Android app, within an app?

Tags: android

I'm writing a basic application.  One of the features I'm interested in trying to do is to launch another app, INSIDE the app already running.

Eg. I have an app with 3 menu options, 1 and 2 do certain tasks as part of this parent app, menu option 3 launches another app that's installed on the phone.
I'm not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is possible with the [Intents mechanism](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

The exact Intent you'll have to write depend on various factors:

- do you have to provide some data to the launched application?
- do you target a specific application or do you want to let the user choose the application he prefers for that task (in case he has several applications able to do what you need)?
- do you want to ensure that the application is available? (that would be better)
- do you know if the other app provides specific intent-filters to do some tasks?

Edit:

Then, you should be able to start the second application with the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setPackage("com.otherapp.package");
startActivity(i);
```

Place this code in the OnClickListener of your button and that should be enough.

Comment: No data needs to be provided              A specific app is the target, and only target, the app will be definately available, so not an issue at the moment.  Im unusure of your last question?  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.  Will test. :) EDIT:  Where should I place the other app? is it ok if already installed on the phone, or must the source code be placed somewhere specific?

Comment: Well, first, you should read the developer guide fundamentals (http://d.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). The application must be installed on the phone and you have to know its package name (what I included in the sample "com.otherapp.package").

Comment: Didn't actually work, It hung for a few seconds and gave an error.  Hear is my code.  Want to press menu item to launch "setup activity" which should boot into the astro file manager app.

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
                               TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
                String strText = textView.getText().toString();
                if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_setlaunch))) {
                    // Launch the setup Activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(FYPMenuActivity.this, FYPSetupActivity.class));   [[[here is where Kevins code goes, but package is set to astro's - com.metago.astro]]]

Comment: this code then follows Kevins snippet -----------------  } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_scweb))) {
                    // Launch the Scores Activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(FYPMenuActivity.this, FYPScwebActivity.class));
                }

Comment: Hi guys, I am still getting "Sorry! The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."  Trying to launch astro from inside a custom app when I click a menu item button.  Heres my code.