# Opening an application, smaller, within an app?

Tags: android

I want to be able to open a tiny version of an app, within an app, that I can have a custom width/height created for. So in a way, think of a web browser, I want to be able to 'browse' any of the apps, within the main app. Is it possible to program something like this? Running an app within an app?

Answer (score 6):

You can launch another app via an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). But running another app within a view in your app is not possible.

See:

[Launching Android app, within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073671/launching-android-app-within-an-app?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

We could achieve this kind of functionality using Fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html This could be a point to start of with...